# Sending array of objects to WCF

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf

In my application i want to save the data by using jQuery and Ajax.I have a WCF Service.
I want to save a List of Objects by using ajax.I have tried with following code, but it
is not working.

**jquery code :**

> ```
>       var listOfObjects=new Array();
> ```

```
      //creating list of objects
      for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
       {   var MyEntity=new Object();
           MyEntity.TestId =i;
           MyEntity.TestId =i+"testName";
           listOfObjects.push(MyEntity);
       }

        //Saving info
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(listOfObjects),
            url: "../ServiceLayer/myService.svc/SaveResults",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",          
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

**WCF :**

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public void SaveLabResults(List<MyEntity> myEntity)
    {
          var lstEntities=myEntity;
    }
```

**Entity:**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TestId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}
```

In this way i am trying to send the list data.But internal server error is coming.I am not getting where actually i am wrong.Is there any other way to send the list of objects to WCF ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jquery code :**

> ```
>       var listOfObjects=new Array();
> ```

```
      //creating list of objects
      for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
       {   var MyEntity=new Object();
           MyEntity.TestId =i;
           MyEntity.TestId =i+"testName";
           listOfObjects.push(MyEntity);
       }

       var jsonList=JSON.stringify(listOfObjects);
       var dataToSend = '{"myEntity":'+jsonList+'';

        //Saving info
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: dataToSend,
            url: "../ServiceLayer/myService.svc/SaveResults",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",          
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

**WCF :**

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public void SaveLabResults(List<MyEntity> myEntity)
    {
          var lstEntities=myEntity;
    }
```

**Entity:**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TestId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}
```

What i am missing was

```
 1.var jsonList=JSON.stringify(listOfObjects);
 2.var dataToSend = '{"myEntity":'+jsonData+'';
```

The 2nd point myEntity key should be there in the final json object.And the key should
be same as the wcf method object parameter.

Thanks

Comment: This answer really helped me, but for anyone else looking at it there is a mistake in the javascript. var dataToSend = '{"myEntity":'+jsonData+''; should be var dataToSend = '{"myEntity":'+jsonList+'}';

Answer (score 1):

Try `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` for your server method or introduce a root element named "myEntity" in your JSON data prior to calling `JSON.stringify` in your client code.

Comment: Whenever i am trying Bare then {"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"} is coming

Comment: yes Oliver u r right.i included a root element and it worked.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

May be this one is the error:

```
//creating list of objects
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
   {   var MyEntity=new Object();
       MyEntity.TestId =i;
       MyEntity.TestId =i+"testName";
       listOfObjects.push(MyEntity);
   } //-------------------^--------------shouldn't it be capital M
```

and in the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {data : JSON.stringify(listOfObjects)}, //<---not quite sure about it.
```