# Pass list of objects to web-service

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, web-services, object

I have an array of objects

```
let arr = [{"1":"bar"},{"2":"bar"}]
```

which gets sent to a service through ajax inside `data`

the service will then get the array & do stuff.

```
[WebInvoke]
public void getStuff(params Model[] data)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

what would my model need to look like to receive the data `arr`?

### Update:

changed keys in object

Comment: no would be for each object. I'll update

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001755/pass-a-javascript-map-to-json-wcf-service or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372076/post-json-dictionary-without-key-value-text help?

Comment: @test `[{"1":"bar"},{"2":"bar"}]` is not a de-serializable JSON object. The first part should always be the same, unless that's a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: I had JSON.stringify in my ajax data value but I didn't add it to bloat the question. This solved my problem for anybody with the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570317/sending-array-of-objects-to-wcf

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the params:

```
var key = Request.Params[0];
```

then you can use the var "key" to fill a model

Answer (score -1):

The elemenst in this .js array:

```
let arr = [{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"bar"}]
```

Could be represented as this .cs class

```
class Model 
{
    public string foo;
}
```

Because for each object (the bit inside the {}), the default is to map the lhs to a property of the class with the same name (foo).

But, after your edit, if you want this:

```
let arr = [{"1":"bar"},{"2":"bar"}]
```

Then that cannot map to a class so easily, not leat because you can't have a field named '1' but also because it implies that there are many many different options for the lhs of the json.

In that case, consider using a Dictionary

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation to your code

Comment: Please add context to your code sample